# Why removing package by `snap` leaves a symbolic link?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, snap, docker

I installed `docker` with `snap` (i.e. `$ snap install docker`) - but it causes some issues, and it is not recommended.  So I decided to remove `docker` by the command:

```
$ snap remove docker
```

It removes the package properly, but now I have a symbolic link in my home folder:

```
/home/user
+-- snap
|   +-- docker
|       +-- current
```

Where `current` is symbolic link, that points to `321`. I have no idea what it is.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: try this `readlink -f 321` to see where the rabbit hole leads!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Could you add that as answer? I'd like to mark your comment as an answer

Comment: Will do so ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trace the path of that docker file with the command

```
readlink -f 321
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thx